# How to set relationships in Laravel with users having different roles

Tags: php, laravel

For example I am making an app that enables a teacher to manage subjects(add, delete, etc.) while the user will not do the same, he/she will only take the exams made by the teacher.

My question is how can I set the relationship for the teacher and the student since they both use the same Model (User) and table?

Since the teacher must control the subjects, in the User model I will do:

```
public function subjects() { return $this->hasMany(Subject::class); }
```

and in the Subject model:

```
public function user() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }
```

but what about the student?

Since the user has no control of the subjects, he must not have this relationship right? When I do User::subjects(), no matter what the role of the user the subjects() function in the User model will be called right so how can I only assign the role to the teacher not to the student?

Should I do :

```
public function subjects() { 
    // for student 
    if($this->role == 'student') { 
        return 'You do not own the subjects' 
    }

    // for teacher
    return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
}
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Placing these checks on the controller routes would be the way I would go about it. For example, Restricting access to routes edit/delete for students.

Comment: I don't see any problem with subjects() always returning null for the students. Your code should not call subjects() when the user's role is "student" anyways or at least it should expect to recieve null. For safety measure / debugging you can throw an Exception if you want, but I don't think it's necessary to do any additionnal checks in your subjects() method.

Comment: As already said, you should be checking for authorization well before you get to the point of calling a relationship method. [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware) and [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#creating-policies) are both more appropriate places to do this. Disregard the trash AI-generated answer that's been posted below.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function subjects() {
    return $this->hasMany(Subject::class)->whereHas('user', function ($q) {
        $q->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
            $q->where('name', 'teacher');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.